# compare django template tag to integer

Tags: javascript, django

I want to compare the django template tag to integer in javascript in html. 
Here's my html.

```
       <script>
        {% for schedule in schedules%}
            if({{schedule.get_month}}<10){
                {
                title: '{{schedule.title}}',
                start: new Date({{schedule.get_year}},0{{schedule.get_month}},0{{schedule.get_day}},{{schedule.get_hour}},{{schedule.get_minute}}),
                allDay: false,
                className: 'success'
                },

            }
            else{
                {
                title: '{{schedule.title}}',
                start: new Date({{schedule.get_year}},{{schedule.get_month}},0{{schedule.get_day}},{{schedule.get_hour}},{{schedule.get_minute}}),
                allDay: false,
                className: 'success'
                },
            }

            {% endfor %}
     </script>
```

My return schedulre.get_year is 6. So result of if({{schedule.get_year}}<10) is if(6<10).  But the part get an error (index):213 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if.

What's the problem of if?

If it can't be solved. I want to return the month and day by django datetimefield like 6 ->06, 11->11. 
Here's my models.py

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
Trainer = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='schedule', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
title = models.CharField(max_length=12)
start = models.DateTimeField()

def get_year(self):
    return self.start.year
def get_month(self):
    return self.start.month-1
def get_day(self):
    return self.start.day
def get_hour(self):
    return self.start.hour
def get_minute(self):
    return self.start.minute
```

But I don't know how return 6 -> 06 in model. So I tried it in template but I get 'if' error.

Any advice will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: trt this first so you know that your data from model is correct.

`console.log(typeof {{schedule.get_month}})`

Comment: Why do you think you need `06` rather than just `6`? On the contrary, `6` is perfectly valid as a the month argument to `new Date()`.

Comment: Note though that this script won't do anything useful at all. What are you trying to do with the object that is created in either the `if` or `else` blocks?

Comment: if({{schedule.get_month|add:'0'}}<10). try with this

Comment: Thank you for all comments! I misunderstood, 6 is also working :)